# OnStart Windows Service using Task rather than timer

Tags: design-patterns, queue

I have a LOT more to learn about Task, and how to manage it.  I can use it, and the pitfalls are starting to sink in (error handling and aggregate exceptions), however, I'm looking for the best way using Task to start a window service with a long running process.  I thought I could have found it on the net - but I'm having no luck.

I have a windows Azure Service Bus, that when a message shows up, I have a long process that takes over a minute to complete .  The process monitors a queue, and deals with the work involving that message. Ideally I would like to have X competing consumers all monitoring the same queue.

Point to examples, or just a nod to show direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with WebJobs - allowing to use a competing consumer pattern, without the need of managing parallel tasks within a windows service, and do all the thread management.  Bonus is a quick and easy means to write execution context directly to a logger, which is surfaced via the portal.